# Force a view to redraw

Tags: objective-c

I tried to use setNeedsDisplay, but that is very much up to the mercy of the system whether to refresh right the way. Currently I remove and add the subview every time, so the latest content is forced to show. The code works, however it lacks gracefulness.

```
        [myView removeFromSuperview];
        [myView release];
        myView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, MY_VIEW_Y, 320.0, MY_VIEW_H)];
        [self.view addSubview:myView];
        //[self.myView setNeedsDisplay];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront: myView];
```

Comment: What about `cardView` are you trying to update that isn't working?

Comment: Please post the implementation of `CardView`. I don't understand how you've designed the class to be updated.

Comment: You still haven't explained how you expect the object to update if you're not providing it with new values to use in the `-drawRect:` method. I don't understand the problem you're having.

Comment: If your problem happens when you use `setNeedsDisplay`, then you need to show us the code that calls `setNeedsDisplay`.  You should also show us your implementation of `drawRect:`.

Answer (score 2):

Your view should be getting redrawn at the next drawing cycle. Is this not happening or is this too slow for you? ... i.e.: how fast do you need it to redraw and what latency are you seeing between calling setNeedsDisplay and drawRect being called?

If you need more precise control of the drawing, you may need to use a view backed by CAEAGLLayer, in which case it runs from openGL and setNeedsDisplay has no effect.

Comment: How slow is too slow. What's the order of magnitude of the latency?

Comment: Cool, that's what I wanted to know. You have a bug in your code because setNeedsDisplay works on the next drawing pass which should happen very soon. Check the following 1. Is your setNeedsDisplay getting hit in the debugger 2. Is your drawRect getting hit in the debugger 3. Are you holding up the main run loop for some reason?